# Effects of EMP in superconductor-based devices/equipment?

Tags: electromagnetism

What are possible effects of electromagnetic pulse / EMP on superconductor-based devices/equimpent/transportation?

Are they resilient or more sensitive to EMP?

Comment: Could you please specify what is EMP? Is it electromagnetic pulse?

Comment: Yes. I updated the text.